# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menus not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

So I am working on a bootstrap website using the template "[Butterfly](http://graphicburger.com/butterfly-free-bootstrap-theme/)"  So far, everything is working fine besides the navbar when resized for mobile devices.  The dropdown menu will not open when on a mobile device for some reason.  I am using a PHP include tag to include the same navbar on every page of the site easily and allow easy updates to it.

```
<?php include_once("template/menu.html"); ?>
```

Navbar code:

```
<!--Mobile version of header-->
    <ul class="toggle">
      <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><span style="cursor:pointer">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Properties
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Link 3<span class="label label-success label-as-badge">0 New</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2<span class="label label-success label-as-badge">3 New</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3<span class="label label-success label-as-badge">Nothing here</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div></span>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#work_outer">Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Portfolio">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#client_outer">Apply</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the CSS for navbar:

```
.nav-right{
    float:right;
    }

.nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    }
.nav ul.toggle{
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    }

.nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 23px;
    }

.nav ul li:first-child{
    /*margin:0px;*/
    }

.nav ul li:last-child{
    margin:0 0 0 23px;
    }

.nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#222222;
    font-family:'Dosis';
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;    
    }
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#49b5e7;
    }
```

Here is some more css for the navbar.  Most is default from bootstrap.css but i'm not sure:

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.open > a {
  outline: 0;
}
.dropdown-header {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #999999;
}
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 990;
}
```

THANKS for reading, any help is much appreciated.  If you need any more information, just ask and I'll find it in my code and post it.  Thanks again everyone!

Comment: You should post a working example of the problem. The code you posted doesn't produce anything like the theme you linked to in your question. Chances are this is an issue with the loading of the JS thats needed for the mobile navs functionality.

Comment: You should load `jquery` at the end of the `body` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a media query (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
and change the dropdown menu in that css

Comment: Ok.  I think that will work.  I will try it soon thanks!